# Sentry ignoring exception configuration not working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sentry

I am trying to add ignore configuration for Sentry, but it's not working, still receive that exception on Sentry page.

`io.sentry:sentry-log4j2` version is **6.12.1** and Spring Boot version is **2.5.8**.

```
sentry.ignored-exceptions-for-type=java.lang.RuntimeException,java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

This is the documentation that I am checking.
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/spring/configuration/

Any idea what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Sentry ignore functionality works for `sentry-spring` dependency, to use this option with `sentry-log4j2`, you can check out this answer that I replied for different problem that I shared before.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715893/2165146