# How to do unit test with Sentry?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, sentry

I want to write test cases for ignored exceptions which will not send to Sentry, how can it be done with or without connecting any Sentry instance ?

Comment: Do you want to that exceptions are not sent or test your code?

Comment: @vaind test exceptions actually ignored or not.

Answer (score 1):

Can't test whole Sentry functionality but I created a test case for `setBeforeSend()` method, which I extracted that part and created a unit test for that one and then will test if an ignored exception is really "ignored".

```
public class SentryConfiguration {

    public SentryConfiguration(List<String> sentryIgnoredExceptions) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(sentryIgnoredExceptions)) {
            Sentry.init(options -> {
                        options.setEnableExternalConfiguration(true);
                        options.setDsn("");
                        options.setBeforeSend((event, hint) -> checkBeforeSend(event, sentryIgnoredExceptions));
                    }
            );
        }
    }

    public SentryEvent checkBeforeSend(SentryEvent event, List<String> sentryIgnoredExceptions) {
        for (String sentryIgnoredException : sentryIgnoredExceptions) {
            String[] splitException = sentryIgnoredException.split("#");

            Throwable throwable = event.getThrowable();
            if (throwable != null
                    && splitException[0].equals(throwable.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    && !(splitException.length > 1
                    && !(throwable.getMessage() != null
                    && Arrays.stream(splitException).skip(1).anyMatch(e -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(throwable.getMessage(), e))))) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return event;
    }

}
```

Created mock bean for that;

```
public class SentryConfigurationMock extends SentryConfiguration {
    public static SentryEvent lastEvent;
    public static boolean isEventIgnored;

    public SentryConfigurationMock(List<String> sentryIgnoredExceptions) {
        super(sentryIgnoredExceptions);
    }

    public void reset() {
        isEventIgnored = false;
        lastEvent = null;
    }

    @Override
    public SentryEvent checkBeforeSend(SentryEvent event, List<String> sentryIgnoredExceptions) {
        lastEvent = event;

        SentryEvent sentryEvent = super.checkBeforeSend(event, sentryIgnoredExceptions);
        if (Objects.isNull(sentryEvent)) {
            isEventIgnored = true;
        }

        return sentryEvent;
    }
}
```

Then created a test class for that method ;

```
public class SentryConfigurationTest {

    @Test
    public void should_ignore_exception() {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException("test12345");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            SentryEvent lastEvent = sentryConfigurationMock.getLastEvent();
            Assert.assertNotNull(lastEvent);
            Assert.assertTrue(sentryConfigurationMock.isEventIgnored());
        }
    }
}
```